# The listener of SelectedTextProperty of a TextField fails

Tags: javafx

I have a `TextField` with a listener that is triggered every time I select a portion of text it contains. For example, in the following situation, after selecting the two digits on the left I replaced by 5:

[image]

This works properly, but this one not:

[image]

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
```

The code is:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SelectedText extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(textField);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 100, 100);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        textField.selectedTextProperty().addListener((final ObservableValue<? extends String> ov,
                final String oldSelection, final String newSelection) -> {
                    System.out.println ("text selected: " + newSelection); 
                });
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }  
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with that code snippet. Could you create a [mcve].

Comment: It is a known bug in Java that has not yet been fixed. You'll have to rephrase your code to use other different listeners.